# AWS Cognito not able to delete user using aws sdk

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-js, aws-amplify

I am using aws cognito create customers for my application and store their id in my database to keep local records.
I have used local database for admin users.
I have used aws amplify to sign up users
But i am facing issue in deleting a user when logged in as admin.

I am using aws sdk for it

```
aws.config.update({
    accessKeyId: "string",
    secretAccessKey: "string",
    region: process.env.REACT_APP_REGION
});


aws.config.credentials = new aws.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_IDENTITYPOOLID,
    AllowUnauthenticatedIdentities: true,
    AccountId: 'string',
    RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::string:role/Cognito_WebReactAuth_Role',
});


var params  = {
    UserPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_USERPOOLID,
    Username: id,
};

var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new aws.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminDeleteUser(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

But it give me error Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity and CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config

What i am trying to achieve is logging as admin using my local database and listing of all the customers from local database. When i will click on delete user from cognito as well as local database will be deleted.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All the admin services can be used like this. AWS documentation is hard to understand.
This example for admin should be put somewhere as it can come handy.

```
import aws from 'aws-sdk';

aws.config.accessKeyId = process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_ACCESS_KEY;
aws.config.secretAccessKey = process.env.REACT_APP_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY;
aws.config.region = process.env.REACT_APP_REGION;

let params = {
   UserPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_USERPOOLID,
   Username: user.cognitoClientId,
};

let cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new aws.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminDeleteUser(params, function (err, data)
```

No need to add following, as it is done for frontend only.

```
aws.config.credentials = new aws.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
   IdentityPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_IDENTITYPOOLID,
   AllowUnauthenticatedIdentities: true,
   AccountId: 'string',
   RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::string:role/Cognito_WebReactAuth_Role',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

[image]
lambda function to delete the user, I have tested it, Its working. with response.
Make sure to make cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminDeleteuser() function as await to get not null response.
else it will come and go back without waiting to get response